# Using NSPredicate to get the max count of an ID

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

I have an entity in core data declared like so:

```
PHOTOS
userId (pk)
photoId (pk)
photoData

// The predicate request
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photos"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId = %@", userId];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"photoId" ascending:NO];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
```

I actually want to get the maximum photoId for a userId so that I can insert the next record.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That seems to be the right way to do it.

Comment: I'd also add a `request.fetchLimit = 1` to reduce the result to the  requested `Photo` only. BTW: When naming an entity, it's good practice to use singular name (`Photo`) not plural (`Photos`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting with `fetchLimit` set to 1 is much less code and just as efficient in most use cases. So your solution is preferable.

Alternatively, for even less code, you can leave out the sort descriptor and fetch limit and just filter in memory (Apple also recommends this):

```
NSNumber *max = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@max.photoId"];
```

Comment: if results is empty, does it still return 0 or do I need to check that

Comment: In the above, `max` should result in `nil`. `max.longIntValue` would then be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend using an NSExpression in combination with your fetchrequest. The code below will fetch the biggest identifier, but if you add a predicate, it should do what you are looking for, with slightly faster SQL-queries...

```
 + (NSArray*)fetchMostRecentIdentifierFromContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc_ error:(NSError**)error_ {
    NSParameterAssert(moc_);
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photos" inManagedObjectContext:moc_];
  [request setEntity:entity];
  [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    // Create an expression for the key path.
  NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"identifier"]]];

  NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
  [expressionDescription setName:@"photoId"];
  [expressionDescription setExpression:maxExpression];
  [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger16AttributeType];
  [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];


    NSArray *result = [moc_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error_) *error_ = error;
    return result;
}
```

More info:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/01/19/core-data-queries-using-expressions.html